# Accessing custom blob metadata in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I upload a blob using the SDK and add some metadata e.g:

```
blob.Metadata["fileLoadId"] = "5";
```

I then have a logic app that is triggered by this new blob, but I want to be able to access this 'fileLoadId' within the logic app so I can pass it to functions.

In the logic app the blob has the following metadata:

```
{
   "Id": "L2VtcGxveWVlcy9lbXBsb3llZS10ZXN0LmNzdg==",
  "Name": "employee-test.csv",
  "DisplayName": "employee-test.csv",
  "Path": "/employees/employee-test.csv",
  "LastModified": "2017-09-04T10:13:21Z",
  "Size": 507,
  "MediaType": "text/csv",
  "IsFolder": false,
  "ETag": "\"0x8D4F37D9209EC29\"",
  "FileLocator": "L2VtcGxveWVlcy9lbXBsb3llZS10ZXN0LmNzdg==",
 "LastModifiedBy": null
}
```

but doesn't include any custom metadata related to the blob.

Is it possible to get access to all the metadata in a logic app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to get access to all the metadata in a logic app?

I also can repro that`doesn't include any custom metadata related to the blob` on my side. I find that there is already a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/17426296-read-custom-properties-metadata-from-blockblob) about this, you can vote it up.

If it is possible we could use the **service bus/storage queue trigger** to do that. After we upload the blob then we could send the blob info include the customized metadata to the **servicebus/storage** queue message. And then we could get the message info with logic app. About how to use storage queue please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues).

Comment: Thanks, given the feedback a vote. I thought of setting the blob as an input to my function but thought it was a bit of an overhead bringing in the actual file contents rather than just the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-metadata 
 
HTTP action to get blob custom metadata using api from above link and get the metadata from response headers